# How to get passed arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script, I am not able to get the argument passed on the function ('hello').

What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Fabric</title>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Snip = function () {
        };
        Snip.prototype.methodB = function () {
            alert('do smt');
        };
        Snip_Nav = (function (Snip) {
            var args = arguments[0]; // problem here
            var Snip_Nav = function () {
                this.config = {
                    name: args
                };
            };
            $.extend(true, Snip_Nav.prototype, Snip.prototype, {
                init: function () {
                    this.items = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
                },
                methodA: function () {
                    alert(this.config.name);
                }

            });

            return Snip_Nav;

        })(Snip);

        function start() {
            var test1 = new Snip_Nav('hello');
            var test2 = new Snip_Nav();
            test1.methodA();
            test2.methodA();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="start();">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that after the IIFE is executed, the value of `Snip_Nav` is the function:

```
function () {
   this.config = {
      name: args
  };
};
```

which isn't what you expect.

A very easy fix (but it may lead to other issues depending on your whole code), may be to have:

```
function (myArg) {
   this.config = {
      name: myArg
  };
};
```

Comment: How I could possible fix it? or a work around?

Comment: Added solution to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the `arguments` of your **second** `Snip_Nav` definition:

```
Snip_Nav = (function (Snip) {
    var Snip_Nav = function () {
        var args = arguments[0]; // problem SOLVED here
        this.config = {
            name: args
        };
    };
    ...
```